# gcc dump resolved defines

Tags: c, gcc

I have code like

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define SUM (ONE+TWO)
```

How do I dump SUM as "3", the resolved value, in gcc 4.3+?

`gcc -dM -E foo.h` only seems to dump it as is. How do I get the actual value like it's inserted on compilation stage?

Comment: Look at Assembly code produced by compiler.

Comment: But `SUM` isn't 3, it's `ONE+TWO`. Macros are expanded where they appear, that's how they work. Try by undefining `ONE` after the definition of `SUM`, redefining it to something different, then inserting SUM into the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  As far as the compiler is concerned, the line `printf("%d\n", SUM)` before preprocessing is indistinguishable from the line `printf("%d\n", 1+2)`.  The compiler just happens to perform an optimization called [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding), even at the default optimization level (`-O0`), which turns the result into a constant 3 at runtime.

There's not really a good way to see the output of these optimizations.  You could use the `-S` option to view the generated assembly code and see what that looks like, but if your program is anything larger than a toy, that will be a lot of manual effort.  You could also look at the parse tree by using one of the `-fdump-tree` options (see the GCC man page).

Comment: i've already understood that... that was a bad question in the first place. I guess I have to go another way. Thanks for the tip on constant folding, that was quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "dump" `SUM` as 3 because `SUM` isn't 3 in any meaningful sense, it's just a sequence of the three tokens `ONE`, `+` and `TWO`. What it turns into depends on the context where it is expanded.

Macros are expanded where they appear in the source, macro replacements are just strings of tokens until then.

You can test this like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define SUM ONE+TWO
int a = SUM;
#undef ONE
#define ONE 2
int b = SUM;

int main()
{
     printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n", a, b);
     return 0;
}
```

Here's another example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define SUM ONE+TWO
int main()
{
     /* prints 6, not 2 */
     printf("5 - SUM = %d\n", 5 - SUM);
     return 0;
}
```

With this example there's no way you can justify `SUM` being `3`.

Comment: ok, there was a mistake in my code, what if I write it as `#define SUM (ONE+TWO)`? it still prints the untouched, but last example will show 2. any way to dump it as 3?

Comment: I guess I should stick with "outputting" method like printf or write external parser for dumps. Yeah, my question was initially bad-formed.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the other answers, there's definitely a solution to this problem, especially with gcc extensions. Parse the output of `gcc -dM` and generate a C file containing lines of the form `__typeof__(MACRO) foo = MACRO;` and go from there. Without `__typeof__` you could still handle all arithmetic types fairly well by just using `long double`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to stop at the precompiler stage (`-E`) and examine that output.