# getting the value of compile-time expressions in C

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any way to have the C compiler (XC16 in my case, which is based on gcc) dump the results of compile-time expressions?

We have lots of #defines like

```
#define FOO 37.6
#define FOO_BASE 0.035
#define FOO_FIXEDPOINT (int16_t)(FOO/FOO_BASE)
```

and I would like to know the actual numbers that the compiler reduces these expressions to.

Note that this is **NOT** the same thing as wanting to know what the preprocessor outputs; the preprocessor does not compute math, it only substitutes in things. If I look at the preprocessor output, I get (effectively)

```
#define FOO_FIXEDPOINT (int16_t)(37.6/0.035)
```

and it's the **compiler**, not the preprocessor, which figures out a value.

---

Another important point here: I do have the freedom to create a special .c file that does things like

```
#include "foo.h"

const int16_t foo_fixedpoint = FOO_FIXEDPOINT;
```

so that I'm providing a place for the compiler to do its work and put the results as a constant.

---

Just as a complete self-contained example, if I put this into foo.c and run `xc16-gcc.exe -E foo.c`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define FOO 37.6
#define FOO_BASE 0.035
#define FOO_FIXEDPOINT (int16_t)(FOO/FOO_BASE)

int main()
{
   int x = FOO_FIXEDPOINT;
}
```

I get this output:

```
[... typedefs elided ...]
int main()
{
   int x = (int16_t)(37.6/0.035);
}
```

Comment: please don't RTFM me. In order to do that, I need to know what to search for.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski -- nope, no gdb (that I know of) for the dsPIC. Also there are dozens of these definitions scattered around the code so I would like to dump all of them automatically.

Comment: @iharob: The preprocessor doesn't compute numbers, it merely performs substitution. So in this example I would get #define FOO_FIXEDPOINT (int16_t)(37.6/0.035) which doesn't help me. I want the *result* of this expression.

Comment: NO IT IS NOT a duplicate. I don't want to dump the #defines, I want to know what the compiler reduces compile-time expressions to.

Comment: Using what you find in those answers should do.

Comment: The question is asking about whether there is a compiler switch of some sort that will dump values that reduce to compile-time constants such as `sizeof(20)` or `40/3.75`. The preprocessor does not perform this. For example, `#define FOO_FIXEDPOINT (int16_t)(FOO/FOO_BASE)` will replace all instances of `FOO_FIXEDPOINT` with the text `(int16_t)(37.6/0.035)`, which will be reduced to a compile-time constant by the compiler.

Comment: thanks Chrono. This is what I said 6 minutes ago, 4 minutes after I asked the question, and 2 minutes before the question was unceremoniously closed.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune You are right, it's a different question, I just reopened.

Comment: thank you. And please in the future give people a little more benefit of the doubt before closing.

Comment: I don't think you can get these values. They get calculated in one of the compiler passes - most likely in the Constant Reduction pass. If you use something like `i = FOO_FIXEDPOINT/2;`, the 'actual' value of `FOO_FIXEDPOINT` may appear nowhere in your executable.

Comment: Well, one thing I can do is create a fake .c file with things like `int16_t foo_fixedpoint = FOO_FIXEDPOINT;` and run the compiler on it. I know the compiler engineer for XC16 in this case so I can get him to tell me which compiler pass to dump out, if that would help...

Comment: The best option I'm aware of is looking at the generated assembly code.

Comment: This is what a debugger is used for: the best if you don't want to modify our program and look at the assembly is to use a debugger.

Comment: I don't like to dup it as compilers always get some new useful options but the question is very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574245/gcc-dump-resolved-defines

Comment: @ouah: I'm ok with marking it as a duplicate... but that question didn't get much attention, and I suspect there *is* a way (answers to question #7574245 say "you can't") if I'm allowed to write a special .c file which acts as a "compilation harness" to facilitate printing out the resolved values... even if it involves ugly parsing of assembly code or gcc internal pass dumps.

Comment: Programming C and C++ is like hitting yourself in the face with a hammer... Why would asking a question about it be any different?  'Mglad I don't C anything except # :)

Comment: Since it's the compiler that determines the computed values, is there a way to get the compiler to just dump certain computed values to a text file? Then I could include it in the git commit and everything.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18808108/125507 though this version has more content

Comment: I solved this by writing a separate .c file meant for the host machine, importing the same .h files, printing the values of the macros (to a .txt file) and then compiling it (using gcc for host) and running it as a post-build step. Then there's a nice summary of the important values that I can commit along with the changes, compare between projects, etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out the flags `-fdump-tree-*` in the [debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) page, to see the output of the intermediate language (a bit low-level but quite readable).

You can use `-fdump-tree-all` to see the file at different stages, but probably all you need is the `-fdump-tree-original`. Look down bellow in the generated `*.original` file to look for your main function:

```
...
;; Function main (null)
;; enabled by -tree-original

{
  int x = 1074;

    int x = 1074;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. one more question. Why does this work this way? if it's the "original" AST, how come the constant-folding happens before this point?

Comment: @JasonS I don't know way, but basic expressions (e.g. 3+4) seems to be evaluated much earlier before tree optimizations stage.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in comments, especially if the numerical macros are not mixed with macros having non-numerical types, it's simple to produce a program that prints their values.

Even though your environment is a cross compiler, this is a useful exercise because all gccs process constant expressions internally with the same code. This does math in extended precision so that compiled constants are within one ULP of the exact value.

So any gcc should give a quite accurate idea of what's going into your code.

In perl:

```
print "#include<stdio.h>\n";
print "#include \"$ARGV[0]\"\n";
print "#define S(X) #X\n";
print "int main(void) {\n";
open F, $ARGV[0] or die $!;
while (<F>) {
  print "  printf(\"%s=%.13g\\n\", S($1), (double)$1);\n" if /#define\s+(\w+)\s+\S/;
}
print "  return 0;\n}\n";
```

Now try it out by running on `math.h`.

```
perl /usr/include/math.h > math_h_syms.c
```

This produces:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "/usr/include/math.h"
#define S(X) #X
int main(void) {
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(INFINITY), (double)INFINITY);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_NAN), (double)FP_NAN);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_INFINITE), (double)FP_INFINITE);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_ZERO), (double)FP_ZERO);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_NORMAL), (double)FP_NORMAL);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_SUBNORMAL), (double)FP_SUBNORMAL);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_SUPERNORMAL), (double)FP_SUPERNORMAL);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_ILOGB0), (double)FP_ILOGB0);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_ILOGBNAN), (double)FP_ILOGBNAN);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(MATH_ERRNO), (double)MATH_ERRNO);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(MATH_ERREXCEPT), (double)MATH_ERREXCEPT);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(math_errhandling), (double)math_errhandling);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_E), (double)M_E);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_LOG2E), (double)M_LOG2E);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_LOG10E), (double)M_LOG10E);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_LN2), (double)M_LN2);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_LN10), (double)M_LN10);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_PI), (double)M_PI);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_PI_2), (double)M_PI_2);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_PI_4), (double)M_PI_4);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_1_PI), (double)M_1_PI);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_2_PI), (double)M_2_PI);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_2_SQRTPI), (double)M_2_SQRTPI);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_SQRT2), (double)M_SQRT2);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(M_SQRT1_2), (double)M_SQRT1_2);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(MAXFLOAT), (double)MAXFLOAT);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_SNAN), (double)FP_SNAN);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(FP_QNAN), (double)FP_QNAN);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(HUGE), (double)HUGE);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(X_TLOSS), (double)X_TLOSS);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(DOMAIN), (double)DOMAIN);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(SING), (double)SING);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(OVERFLOW), (double)OVERFLOW);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(UNDERFLOW), (double)UNDERFLOW);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(TLOSS), (double)TLOSS);
  printf("%s=%.13g\n", S(PLOSS), (double)PLOSS);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
INFINITY=inf
FP_NAN=1
FP_INFINITE=2
FP_ZERO=3
FP_NORMAL=4
FP_SUBNORMAL=5
FP_SUPERNORMAL=6
FP_ILOGB0=-2147483648
FP_ILOGBNAN=-2147483648
MATH_ERRNO=1
MATH_ERREXCEPT=2
math_errhandling=2
M_E=2.718281828459
M_LOG2E=1.442695040889
M_LOG10E=0.4342944819033
M_LN2=0.6931471805599
M_LN10=2.302585092994
M_PI=3.14159265359
M_PI_2=1.570796326795
M_PI_4=0.7853981633974
M_1_PI=0.3183098861838
M_2_PI=0.6366197723676
M_2_SQRTPI=1.128379167096
M_SQRT2=1.414213562373
M_SQRT1_2=0.7071067811865
MAXFLOAT=3.402823466385e+38
FP_SNAN=1
FP_QNAN=1
HUGE=3.402823466385e+38
X_TLOSS=1.414847550406e+16
DOMAIN=1
SING=2
OVERFLOW=3
UNDERFLOW=4
TLOSS=5
PLOSS=6
```

Comment: @JasonS: well no. `math.h` defines these as "Return values for fpclassify" (although my local mingw values are different).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** This doesn't work :-(

Even with the trick for converting integer to a string, the composed value is not evaluated by preprocessor.

```
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#define A 1
#define B 2
#define C A+B

#pragma message("A=" STR(A))
#pragma message("B=" STR(B))
#pragma message("C=" STR(C))
```

compiler output (VS2008):

```
1>A=1
1>B=2
1>C=1+2
```

So preprocessor won't help here.

**Original ANSWER**
As the last resort, if there is no way getting the values from the intermediate files, by means of gcc-options, etc.

I'd grep the source-files for #define, redirect the output in a new .c file and replace #define by `#pragma message`. Calling gcc on this file would list all defines. Of cause provided your compiler supported `#pragma message`.

Comment: hmm. this allows the compiler to perform math calculations and output the results as a message?!

Comment: Unfortunately pragma message only works on strings, and the OP is asking for computed numerical values.  He'd actually have to (for floating point constants) compile printf("%f\n", MACRO);

Comment: ah... yeah, and using printfs is an ugly thing because this is a cross-compiler for an embedded system.

Comment: Oh, how embarrassing, that's right. pragma message won't help on numerical constants, only strings will be printed. Ok than what remains is to create a list of printfs. Of cause, it's not that easy, and will print something only at run-time.